# using system to run install.packages on a remote computer

Tags: r, install.packages

As I'm playing with my cluster of computers, I'm trying to develop some scripts to help me keep the computers on my cluster in sync, as far as packages, versions, etc.  Rather than logging in to each computer and updating all of the packages, I'd like to run a system call through SSH.  I can't seem to get the system call right, however.  Here's an example of what I'm trying to do.

```
system(paste0("C:/PuTTY/plink.exe [SSH stuff] ",
              "RScript -e ",
              "install.packages(", shQuote("HydeNet"), 
              ", repos = ",
              shQuote("http://mirrors.nics.utk.edu/cran/"),
              ")"))
```

Ideally, that would install the `HydeNet` package on the remote computer.  I keep getting this in return:

```
Error: unexpected end of input
Execution halted
Warning message:
running command 'RScript -e install.packages("HydeNet", repos = "http://mirrors.nics.utk.edu/cran/")' had status 1
```

That seems to me like it's a mismatched quote character, or a mismatched parenthesis, but I just can't see the mismatch.  I've tried every permutation of single and double quotes I can think of.  What haven't I thought of yet?

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried that command in your local first.

Syntax of `Rscript` is `Rscript -e "expression in quotes"`

and looks like `install.packages` from `Rscript` expects package name and repo in single quotes.

use this command

```
system(paste0("C:/PuTTY/plink.exe [SSH stuff] ",
       "RScript -e ","\"install.packages(", shQuote("'HydeNet'"), 
       ",repos = ",shQuote("'http://mirrors.nics.utk.edu/cran/'"),")\""))
```

Comment: At least one step closer.  If I take out the plink and SSH stuff (and start at `RScript`, it will run locally, but when I try to pass it through SSH, it fails again with "unexpected end of input".  Which may mean a problem with my configuration on the remote?

Comment: looks like yes..you should also run the same script locally on your remote and see if it works..then you should try to ssh from your local to remote.

Comment: `install.packages` doesn't need single quotes - double quotes work fine. `Rscript -e 'install.packages("HydeNet", repos = "http://mirrors.nics.utk.edu/cran/")'` works locally for me...

Comment: what is your OS? mine is windows..and it does not work without single quotes here..

Comment: I'm on windows, and when run locally, `Rscript -e "install.packages('HydeNet', repos = 'http://mirror.nics.utk.edu/cran/')"` will run on both the local and the remote when run from the command line and within `system`.  As soon as I add the SSH stuff, it fails again.  Apparently it doesn't like going through the server.  I'm confident it isn't the connection, though, as I can run something trivial like `rnorm(100)` through SSH and it will succeed.

Comment: I think what I may do instead is write the `install.packages` command to a file, transfer it to the remote using `PSCP` (part of PuTTY), run it with RScript, and then delete it using R script.  How's that for convoluted. :)

Comment: I am sure there can be a better way to working in clusters with R language..i will also explore more on this..may be we need to explore some solution sort of CI and CD with R.